# AWS Lambda and zip upload from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This feature is not clear to me about the benefits (I didn't find any good documentation):

1. Is it just faster in the case you reuse the same zip for many lambda functions because you upload only 1 time and you just give the S3 link URL to each lambda function?
2. If you use an S3 link, will all your lambda functions be updated with the latest code automatically when you re-upload the zip file, meaning is the zip file on S3 a "reference" to use at each call to a lambda function?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I have been asked "Why do you want the same code for multiple Lambda functions anyway?"
Because I use AWS Lambda with AWS API Gateway so I have 1 project with all my handlers which are actual "endpoints" for my RESTful API.

EDIT #2:
I confirm that uploading a modified version of the zip file on S3 doesn't change the existing lambda functions result.

**If an AWS guy reads this message, that would be great to have a kind of batch update feature that updates a set of selected lambda functions with 1 zip file on S3 in 1 click** (or even an "automatic update" feature that detects when the file has been updated ;-))
Let's say you have 50 handlers in 1 project, then you modify something global impacting all of them, currently you have to go through all your lambda functions and update the zip file manually...

Comment: You can use a trigger on an S3 bucket to automate updating a set of lambda functions when a file is uploaded.

Comment: @AdrianWragg good suggestion, I already use the event feature for other stuff, but that means you use another Lambda function to update the code of other functions right? In my case I use Java and I release with Maven into S3 buckets so I was thinking of using a local script calling the AWS Command Line Interface (update-function-code).

Comment: You're right, yes - I've actually given more detail in my answer below, which also includes a link to a script you can adapt for your requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is imported from the zip to Lambda. It is exactly the same as uploading the zip file through the Lambda console or API. However, if your Lambda function is big (they say >10MB), they recommend uploading to S3 and then using the S3 import functionality because that is more stable than directly uploading from the Lambda page. Other than that, there is no benefit.

So for question 1: no. Why do you want the same code for multiple Lambda functions anyway?

Question 2: If you overwrite the zip you will not update the Lambda function code.

Comment: I think you can also fix that using 1 Lambda function and usage of the API Gateway mapping templates. I use one Lambda function for several endpoints and in the mapping template of each endpoint I specify an extra value (unique for every endpoint) that goes into the `event` of the single Lambda function to distinguish different endpoint requests.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. So I guess you have one handler which acts as a dispatcher according to some variable from your input or context?

Comment: Exactly! And the variable is hardcoded in the mapping template (different for each endpoint).

Comment: By the way, I guess that means you need to use a "global" class for your input, that contains all the possible variables all your endpoints can receive?

Answer (score 4):

To add to other people's use cases, having the ability to update a Lambda function from S3 is extremely useful within an automated deployment / CI process.

The instructions under [New Deployment Options for AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-deployment-options-for-aws-lambda/) include a simple Lambda function that can be used to copy a ZIP file from S3 to Lambda itself, as well as instructions for triggering its execution when a new file is uploaded.

As an example of how easy this can make development and deployment, my current workflow is:

1. I update my Node lambda application on my local machine, and `git commit` it to a remote repository.
2. A Jenkins instance picks up the commit, pulls down the appropriate files, adds them into a ZIP file and uploads this to an S3 bucket.
3. The LambdaDeployment function then automatically deploys this new version for me, without me needing to even leave my development environment.

Comment: but you can still automate the pipeline without having S3 in the middle. you can simply use file path instead of S3 Bucket and Key.

Answer (score 3):

To answer what I think is the essence of your question, AWS allows you to use S3 as the origin for your Lambda zip file because sometimes uploading large files via your browser can timeout.  Also, storing your code on S3 allows you to store it centrally, rather than on your computer and I'm sure there is a CodeCommit tie-in there as well.

Using the S3 method of uploading your code to Lambda also allows you to upload larger files (AWS has a 10MB limit when uploading via web browser).

Comment: I was able to upload a 35MB file yesterday from my browser ;-)

Comment: At this moment, there is a limit of 262 MB (262 144 000 bytes) for the unzipped content of a Lambda package.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /your/workspace

#zips up the new code
zip -FSr yourzipfile.zip . -x *.git* *bin/\* *.zip

#Updates function code of lambda and pushes new zip file to s3bucket for cloudformation lambda:codeuri source
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name  arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:YOURID:function:YOURFUNCTIONNAME --zip-file file://yourzipfile.zip
```

Depends on aws-cli install and aws profile setup

```
aws --profile yourProfileName configure
```

Comment: I had used the aws lambda update-function-code, and it uploads the zip file. so, aren't you uploading it twice? the first with aws lambda, and again with aws s3 cp?